# How do I select a random file in a folder?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I am trying to select a random file of a specific type like *.mp4
from a folder (and optionally  subfolders) using the Windows command line batch script (no PowerShell)

The file full path should be stored in a environment variable for further use

How can I achieve this?

Comment: To the off-topic voters - questions about windows batch file programming are on-topic at [so]

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I select a random file in a folder?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem store the matching file names in list
dir /b *.txt /s 2> nul > files
rem count the match files
type files | find "" /v /c > tmp & set /p _count=<tmp 
rem get a random number between 0 and count-1
set /a _random=%random%*(%_count%)/32768
rem we can't skip 0 lines
if %_random% equ 0 (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('type files') do (
    set _randomfile=%%i
    echo !_randomfile!
    goto :eof
    )
) else (
  for /f "tokens=* skip=%_random%" %%i in ('type files') do (
    set _randomfile=%%i
    echo !_randomfile!
    goto :eof
    )
)
```

The environment variable `!_randomfile!` will contain the filename of a random file.

Notes:

- Remove `/s` if you don't want to match files in subfolders.
- `0` =< `%RANDOM%` < `32767` so it won't work if you have more than `32766` matching files.

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [random](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html) - The Windows CMD shell contains a dynamic variable called `%RANDOM%` that can be used to generate random numbers.

Comment: Hi david...  good answer... but I think we can reduce that code (sorry I am an optimizer by nature) and create some error-prevention mecanism for the file number (file count before select)... THX

Comment: @ZEE I'm not sure what you with "file count before select" and "error prevention"? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: If we count the files,,, then we can assure a random number will always be in the considered range!

Error prevent... no file selected outside the given range... detect if selected file exists and is readable... etc.

;-)

Comment: @ZEE Please read the answer again especially the comments (`rem` statements). First I count the files. Then I get a random number that is the correct range. The files must exist or else `dir` wouldn't have found them to be counted, The **only** thing not checked is that the file is readable.

Comment: @ZEE How do you suggest checking if an mp4 file is readable?

Comment: Hi David... I would suggest something like ( type file.ext >nul & if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo "FILE NOT ACCESIBLE" )...                                                                                                           as you surely know the type is not the best option... if you are using GNU tools or CYGWIN in your windows just use ( tail -c 1 file.ext & ... ) instead of type... this way you only try to read 1 byte from the file...

Comment: @ZEE The answer was written for you, feel free to add whatever checking you want to your batch file ;) If you really want to be clever use a program to read the file and see if it containls a valid mp4 header ... you will also need to work out how to choose another file if there is an error. That will be a nice learning exercise for you!